# how to do getter to the root object in js?

Tags: javascript, typeorm

In JavaScript, how to do getter to object in the root level?

I mean how to create getter for this object:

```
 const userModel = {
   get() { return { foo: true, ... }; }
 }
```

and access to it by `userModel.foo; // true`. the code gives me `userModel.get()..` which not expect what I need.

The idea is go invoke `get` when I access to `userModel`.

Is it possible to do with js?

I am using the typeorm library and I have models for example User.

typeorm is able me to use this model by using this syntax:

```
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';
const b = await getConnection().getRepository(User).findOne({...})...
```

now I want to create UserModel that do this:

```
getConnection().getRepository(User)
```

as:

```
export const userModel = {
     get() { return getConnection().getRepository(User) }
   }
```

so can I use it as:

```
userModel.findOne({...});
```

And I can't just use:

```
export const userModel = getConnection().getRepository(User);
```

Because the connection is not initialized yet, so it throws an error.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, however it requires some deprecated hacks, so no you don't want that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: *"Because the connection is not initial yet, so it throw me an error."* What is the error?

Comment: Hi, it is possible using Proxy, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
const getConnection = (model) => ({
  getRepository: (model) => {
    return { findOne: () => (model) }
  }
});


const User = {
  //...user model,
   name: "Jonh Smith"
}
   

class ProxyModel {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
        return  new Proxy({},  {get: (function(target, name) {
                       const repo = getConnection().getRepository(this);
                       if(name in repo) {
                         return repo[name];
                       }
                }).bind(this.model)})
  }
  
}

const userModel = new ProxyModel(User);

console.log(userModel.findOne());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define getter properly:

```js
const userModel = {
   get foo() { return { foo: true }; }
 }
 
 console.log(userModel.foo)
```

Comment: no I said the idea is to invoke the getter of userModel. the getter is not for foo method.

Comment: Can you elaborate more with a snippet of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AadilMehraj I believe what OP wants is when ``userModel`` being assigned it will invoke the get method. kinda pub/sub